# Showing the tensor product spans a vector space, and interpreting things

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

The question is as follows:

> Prove that the tensor products $\tau\otimes\theta\in L(V,W;F)$ where $\tau\in V$ (suspect typo for $\tau\in V^*$ - the book even defines this above) and $\theta\in W$ (again, $\theta\in W^*$) span $L(V,W;F)$.
>
> However show that except in very special cases $L(V,W;F)$ does not consist entirely of tensor products $\tau\otimes\theta$. That is usually there are members of $L(V,W;F)$ which can only be expressed as sums of two or more such $\tau\otimes\theta$, determin the special cases.

This question comes from `Tensor Analysis on Manifolds` problem 2.8.1

### My attempt

---

Well the first step is to deal with span, so:

- Let $f\in L(V,W;F)$ be given, so $f:V\times W\rightarrow F$ and it's bilinear

  - Let $(v,w)\in V\times W$ be given (I will show function equality) then:
    $f(v,w)=f(\sum^n_{i=1}v_ie_i,\sum_{j=1}^mw_ie'_i)$ where $\{e_i\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{e'_j\}$ of $W$
    $=\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^m_{j=1}v_iw_jf(e_i,e'_j)$

Which looks like I've done more on paper!

Where do I go from here? Also it looks *a little* like a matrix is involved here.

I think that the "matrix" $[f(e_i,e'_j)]_{n,m}$ IS an element of $L(V,W;F)$ surely, and if you pre-multiply by the $v$ as a row-vector, and post multiply by $w$ you infact get the result.

Great, I've just proved to myself that a matrix can represent a bilinear form. Each entry would be a "basis vector" so the dimension is $mn$, right?

The special ones rumoured to exist number $mn$ and are "given" by that matrix I mentioned having a $1$ in one position only, right? Up to a scalar of that of course.

Lastly, this is self learning.  (I have to edit here for some reason)

Comment: I imagine $V,W$ are vector spaces, and $F$ is the base field?

Comment: Yes @DanielRobert-Nicoud , of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$L(V,W;F) \cong L(V\otimes W;F) = (V\otimes W)^* \cong V^*\otimes W^*$$
by the definition of tensor product by universal property. As $V^*\otimes W^*$ is spanned by the pure tensors $\tau\otimes\theta$, we are done (up to proving that the dual of the tensor is the tensor of the duals).

**Note:** This proof works equally well in infinite dimension, whereas the methods you were trying to use (choosing a basis etc.) would probably yield only a proof for the finite dimensional case.

Comment: Sorry for late tick.